# How to find all String literal in my android project and move it to strings.xml file

Tags: android

I'm currently working on the Android project. I'm mostly put all the string literals in strings.xml file. But in few cases, I directly inserted few strings in Java file directly.

Now, I want to give multilingual support for my project. So, that I have to find all string literal in my android project and want to move it to strings.xml. The manual process was too much time-consuming. Any other easy way to achieve this task in Android studio?

Comment: i don't think so there is any way to do this as per my knowledge

Comment: I'm having many java files. Searching each java file takes lot of time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:
Go to >Analyze>Inspect code e click ok on the pop up, after a few minutes, inspection results will be visible, and you should find hardcoded strings under "Android>Lint>Internationalization-Hardcoded text" 
[image: Android Lint]

Comment: Based on hard coded text warning I find all string literals

Comment: thats great +1 from my side

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)